# How can I disable radio buttons or radio groups using sharedpreferences?

Tags: android

I already tried these set of codes:

```
radioButton.setEnabled(false);
radioButton.setClickable(false);
```

but it didn't work for me because when I tried to go back again to the activity with radio buttons, it will be clickable again.

What I want is that when I click it once , it will not be clickable again even if I tried to go back to the activity.

These were the codes of my activity

```
public class TeacherSideQuestion extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question1);

        Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        Button btnCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCheckTeacher1);

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                        TeacherSideQuestion2.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });

        btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SharedPreferences my_preferences = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = my_preferences.edit();
                RadioButton rbtnTeacher1_1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbtnTeacher1_1);
                RadioButton rbtnTeacher1_2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbtnTeacher1_2);
                RadioButton rbtnTeacher1_3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbtnTeacher1_3);

                if (rbtnTeacher1_1.isChecked()) {

                    Toast.makeText(TeacherSideQuestion.this, "Correct",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    rbtnTeacher1_1.setClickable(false);
                    rbtnTeacher1_2.setClickable(false);
                    rbtnTeacher1_3.setClickable(false);

                    if (rbtnTeacher1_1.isChecked()) {
                        editor.putInt("key1", 1);
                    } else {
                        editor.putInt("key1", 0);
                    }
                    editor.commit();

                } else if (rbtnTeacher1_2.isChecked()) {

                    Toast.makeText(TeacherSideQuestion.this, "Incorrect",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    rbtnTeacher1_1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    rbtnTeacher1_1.setClickable(false);
                    rbtnTeacher1_2.setClickable(false);
                    rbtnTeacher1_3.setClickable(false);

                    if (rbtnTeacher1_2.isChecked()) {
                        editor.putInt("key1", 0);
                    }
                    editor.commit();

                } else if (rbtnTeacher1_3.isChecked()) {

                    Toast.makeText(TeacherSideQuestion.this, "Incorrect",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    rbtnTeacher1_1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    rbtnTeacher1_1.setClickable(false);
                    rbtnTeacher1_2.setClickable(false);
                    rbtnTeacher1_3.setClickable(false);

                    if (rbtnTeacher1_3.isChecked()) {
                        editor.putInt("key1", 0);
                    }
                    editor.commit();

                } else {

                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have u Written in condition? That when to Enabled and when to disable?

Comment: And can you post that what you have done so far

Comment: Yes. I already made a condition but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check what is value in `sharedpreferences`?  As per value you need to set

```
radioButton.setEnabled(false).
```

Post your code, I will explain you more about how to handle this.

**Edit :**

As per your code, You need to check checked states when user click on Submit button.

You can do like following.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.temp);

        SharedPreferences _mypref = getApplicationContext()
                .getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0); // <--- 0 - for private

        Editor editor = _mypref.edit();

        first = _mypref.getString("first", "");
        second = _mypref.getString("second", "");

        Log.e("=first==>", "===>" + first);
        Log.e("=second==>", "===>" + second);
        rbtnTeacher1_1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioMale);
        rbtnTeacher1_2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioFemale);
        if (first.length() >= 0) {
            if (first.equals("true")) {
                rbtnTeacher1_1.setChecked(true);

            } else {
                rbtnTeacher1_1.setChecked(false);

            }
        }

        if (second.length() >= 0) {
            if (second.equals("true")) {
                rbtnTeacher1_2.setChecked(true);

            } else {
                rbtnTeacher1_2.setChecked(false);

            }
        }

    }

    public void onCheck(View v) {

        if (rbtnTeacher1_1.isChecked() == true) {

            SharedPreferences _mypref = getApplicationContext()
                    .getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0); // <--- 0 - for private

            Editor editor = _mypref.edit();
            editor.putString("first", "true");
            editor.commit();
        } else {
            SharedPreferences _mypref = getApplicationContext()
                    .getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0); // <--- 0 - for private

            Editor editor = _mypref.edit();
            editor.putString("first", "false");
            editor.commit();
        }

        if (rbtnTeacher1_2.isChecked() == true) {

            SharedPreferences _mypref = getApplicationContext()
                    .getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0); // <--- 0 - for private

            Editor editor = _mypref.edit();
            editor.putString("second", "true");
            editor.commit();

        } else {
            SharedPreferences _mypref = getApplicationContext()
                    .getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0); // <--- 0 - for private

            Editor editor = _mypref.edit();
            editor.putString("second", "false");
            editor.commit();
        }

    }
```

And your xml looks like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioSex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="male" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="female" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onCheck"
        android:text="Check" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Select radio any of them, click on check button. Now when you come again to your activity you can see selected radio button which you checked.

Thanks.

Comment: Mr Dreams , can I know how to post my codes ?
I'm just new to this site that's why I dont know how to post some codes .

Answer (score 0):

In oncreate check below code.

```
        SharedPreferences my_preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
        int i = my_preferences.getInt("key1", 0);
        if(i == 1)
           // set clickable false
```